# Fail to load Chrome extension using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am new using python and selenium. I am working on a project that requires the use of a chrome extension. I spent a couple of days trying to figure out why I could not manage to load my extension and ran out of ideas. I am sure I am missing out something obvious for average coders but it's too fresh for me to findout by myself.

Here is my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import chromedriver_binary
options = wd.ChromeOptions()
wd = wd.Chrome()

options.add_extension(r'C:\Desktop\switchy.crx')
```

I am not getting any error message but I am not getting any result on the webpage. No icon for the extension, and no extensions visible in the extensions menu.

What am I missing ?
Thanks a lot for your time.